# Proverb/idiom thats getting together to fight common enemy but killing weakling to fight among each other

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

Proverb/idiom thats applicable to animal kingdom for when a group of monkeys/lions.. would join hands together to fight unitedly against the common external threat to save their resources, but when the fight for resources is between them, they become their individual self and deprive off resources to the weakest among them.

Comment: They are _allies by necessity_ when the need arises.

Comment: "Politics stops at the water's edge" springs to mind, for loose interpretations of "animal kingdom".

Comment: "Nothing binds a people to their leader like a common enemy. Voters don't change governments during war - Harvey Fierstein" If I am right, I got some thing for the first part. But I cannot get any thing for the rest of the part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to put differences aside (for a common cause)

> She added that it was vital for everyone to "come together, put
>   differences aside and fight to secure these vital jobs". 
>  [BBC
>   article](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-scotland-24825960)

This is a beautiful speech by Ronald Reagan which relates directly to this: [Alien speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ag44dRO8LEA)

or

politics makes strange bedfellows

> Proverb. People who would normally dislike and avoid one another will
>   work together if they think it is politically useful to do so.
>   [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Politics+makes+strange+bedfellows)

Can also be said "makes *for* strange bedfellows." This phrase can be used more generically without using the word "politics", you can use the general term "makes odd/strange bedfellows"
[Link](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+strange+bedfellows)

Also:

> the enemy of my enemy is my friend
>  [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_enemy_of_my_enemy_is_my_friend)

Think of the Allies making a deal with the devil (Stalin).

Answer (score 1):

*"Better the devil you know"*
A proverb that refers to the fact that a known enemy or threat is preferable to an unknown, and usually used to justify cooperation with customary enemies in the face of an outside force.

*"The lesser of two evils"*
Given a choice between two threats or enemies, one is definitely preferable, even if only for the fact that's not as bad as the other.

*"United we stand, divided we fall"*
Refers to the need for unity before an outside threat. Is a fairly positive saying - it's used to motivate and inspire cooperation, rather than justify a choice between two enemies or threats.